# Base toString off what traits are mixed In

Tags: scala

Just working on a proof of concept library. Trying to abstract where possible and mix in traits rather than inheritance, also with this library theres really only one common trait between all instances of Character, there is no class object at all just traits mixed in to build a case object. Trying to make an intelligent-ish toString Implementation, that recognises the traits I've mixed in and alters the toString accordingly. My current theory is to have something like this:

```
//Completely wrong, just a rough pseudocode of one potential ideal
implicit class CharImpl[A <: Character](a: A){

  def toString:String = {
    for(
      i ← _:HasName ⇒ s"Name: ${a.name}"
      j ← _:HasAbbreviation ⇒ s"Abbreviation: ${a.castTo[HasAbbreviation].abbreviation}"
      k ← _:HasUnicode ⇒ s"Unicode: ${a.castTo[HasUnicode].unicode}"
      l ← _:HasDecimal ⇒ s"Decimal: ${a.castTo[HasDecimal].decimal}"
    ) {(i,j,k,l) mkString "\n"}
  }
}
```

The other option is to have each trait require a toString implementation(probably would use a different name though). Then list all the traits mixed in that have this toString function. Then make a single string from all the toString methods on the traits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about overriding `toString` using `super.toString` plus something new?

```
trait A { override def toString: String = super.toString + " with A" }

trait B { override def toString: String = super.toString + " with B" }

trait C { override def toString: String = super.toString + " with C" }

class D { override def toString: String = super.toString + " D" }

scala> new D with C with A
res0: D with C with A = $anon$1@4df5014e D with C with A

scala> new D with C with B
res1: D with C with B = $anon$1@29042f37 D with C with B

class E extends C with A { override def toString: String = "E " + super.toString }

scala> new E
res3: E = E E@40145d8e with C with A
```

Comment: I never knew super called all toString methods. I thought it only called 1 unless specified. Thanks for the help. I've ended up modifying this slightly But It's working great!